I want to ask if there is an existing solution to the communication problem between desktop applications. Can it be submitted in software engineering?
May I ask if my following question can be asked in software engineering?

I plan to write multiple desktop applications using PySide. These desktop applications need to work collaboratively, so this should involve communication between applications (inter-process communication).
Is such a scenario common in software architecture design? Are there mature framework solutions that can be directly referred to?

I am not sure if my above question can be directly asked in software engineering, so I consult in meta first.

The topicality - software architecture and design - is fine, but the specific questions aren't a good fit.

Is such a scenario common in software architecture design?

I'm not sure if we can answer this question. I doubt there are facts and references to support this, so it would be people sharing their opinions. Although sharing opinions and expertise is central to what we do, in most cases, supporting material should be available to back those opinions.

Are there mature framework solutions that can be directly referred to?

We don't provide recommendations for frameworks (or anything else) here. Such questions are closed and often deleted.
My recommendation would be to work on evolving a design based on IPC. If you run into things that you aren't sure about in your design, provide some information about the design (such as class, object, activity, communication, sequence, and/or state diagrams) and ask specific questions about problems that you face. Perhaps you'll run into performance issues, questions about testability or error handling, or something else.
Of course, if you start getting into implementation details, those questions may be better suited to places like Stack Overflow (for getting code working) or Code Review (for improving functional, working code).
